# Python Local Variable As Counter

Tags: python, function, variables, global, local

Using Python 3.7.

Is there any way to use a local variable as a counter?
I tried and received error:

> UnboundLocalError

I did find a recommendation to use a glbal variable which is working, but if possible I would prefer to use a local variable.

Thanks,
-w

Working code using global variable for counter:

```
count = 0
def my_collatz(number):

    global count
    count +=1
    if int(number)%2 == 0:
        r = int((number)//2)
    else:
        r = int(((number * 3) + 1))
    print('Attempt : ' + str(count) + ',' + str(r))

    if r != 1:
        return my_collatz(int(r))

print('Please enter a number : ')
number=input()
my_collatz(int(number))
```

Comment: what are you counting exactly? your code sample seems to only have 1 function call, at which point `count` seems pointless?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh: function shown is recursive, note `return my_collatz(int(r))` line inside function body

Comment: ah, i missed that, gotcha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to move the `count` variable as parameter to the function and increment it each call:

```
def my_collatz(number, count=1):    
    if number % 2 == 0:
        r = number // 2
    else:
        r = (number * 3) + 1

    print('Attempt : ' + str(count) + ',' + str(r))

    if r != 1:
        return my_collatz(r, count + 1)

print('Please enter a number : ')
number=input()
my_collatz(int(number))
```

Prints:

```
Please enter a number : 
6
Attempt : 1,3
Attempt : 2,10
Attempt : 3,5
Attempt : 4,16
Attempt : 5,8
Attempt : 6,4
Attempt : 7,2
Attempt : 8,1
```

---

Other solution is to not use `count` at all, and instead make the function a generator (using `yield`). Then you can use `enumerate()` to obtain your number of steps:

```
def my_collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        r = number // 2
    else:
        r = (number * 3) + 1

    yield r

    if r != 1:
        yield from my_collatz(r)

print('Please enter a number : ')
number=input()

for count, r in enumerate(my_collatz(int(number)), 1):
    print('Attempt : ' + str(count) + ',' + str(r))
```

Comment: Thanks all, here's more on Collatz if you are interested : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture

Answer (score 1):

It is a very strange function indeed. Anyway, you can avoid using a global variable by converting it into an input parameter:

```
count = 0
def my_collatz(number, count):

    count +=1
    if int(number)%2 == 0:
        r = int((number)//2)
    else:
        r = int(((number * 3) + 1))
    print('Attempt : ' + str(count) + ',' + str(r))

    if r != 1:
        return my_collatz(int(r), count=count)

print('Please enter a number : ')
number=input()
my_collatz(int(number),count)
```